# How to create an helm based timescaledb-single deployment on AWS EKS with persistent volume enabled [Error]

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes, timescaledb

I have tried deploying the timescaledb-single via helm chart (0.33.1) on AWS EKS cluster. deployment is working fine without the "persistentVolumes" enabled mode for (data & wal) but if I enable the persistentVolumes, the deployment keeps failing. on further debugging I noticed pending PVC's which might be looking for PV's to be created, not sure what could be the right way to deploy this.

I tried modifying the values.yaml from helm chart "0.33.1" to enable persistentVolumes

[image]

```
## command for first time installation 

helm install timescaledb-eks -f timescaledb-single/values.yaml timescale/timescaledb-single --atomic --dependency-update --description=timescale_on_local
```

```
## upgrade command to try the persistentVolumes modification in "values.yaml" file.

helm upgrade timescaledb-eks -f timescaledb-single/values.yaml timescale/timescaledb-single --atomic --dependency-update --description=timescale_on_local
```

`values.yaml`

```
# This file and its contents are licensed under the Apache License 2.0.
# Please see the included NOTICE for copyright information and LICENSE for a copy of the license.

replicaCount: 2

# To prevent very long names, we override the name, otherwise it would default to
# timescaledb-single (the name of the chart). This field is always truncated to 63 characters.
fullnameOverride: "{{ .Release.Name }}"

# The default Patroni name of the cluster ("scope") is derived from the name of the release,
# but you can override this behaviour here
# https://patroni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SETTINGS.html#global-universal
clusterName: ""

# The major PostgreSQL version to use, defaults to the default version of the Docker image
# However, in pg_upgrade scenarios, you may need to specify an explicit version
version:

image:
  # Image was built from
  # https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-docker-ha
  repository: timescale/timescaledb-ha
  tag: pg14.6-ts2.9.1-p1
  pullPolicy: Always

# There are job and cronjob resources that run during updates or backups that use curl image
# Users in that want to define their own curl image can set it below
# Example: https://github.com/timescale/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/timescaledb-single/templates/job-update-patroni.yaml
curlImage:
  repository: curlimages/curl
  tag: "7.87.0"
  pullPolicy: Always

# By default those secrets are randomly generated.
# To prevent misconfiguration, modifications from helm upgrade won't be applied to those secrets.
# As a result changing secrets cannot be done via helm and need manual intervention.
secrets:
  # This map should contain environment variables that influence Patroni,
  # for example PATRONI_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD or PATRONI_REPLICATION_PASSWORD
  # https://patroni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ENVIRONMENT.html#postgresql
  credentials:
    PATRONI_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD: "pass123"
    PATRONI_REPLICATION_PASSWORD: "pass123"
    PATRONI_admin_PASSWORD: "pass123"

  # Selector used to provision your own Secret containing patroni configuration details
  # This is mutually exclusive with `credentials` option and takes precedence over it.
  # WARNING: Use this option with caution
  credentialsSecretName: ""

  # This map should contain tls key and certifiacte. When empty,
  # helm will generate self-signed certificate.
  certificate:
    tls.crt: ""
    tls.key: ""

  # Selector used to provision your own Secret containing certificate details.
  # This is mutually exclusive with `certificate` option and takes precedence over it.
  # WARNING: Use this option with caution
  certificateSecretName: ""

  # This secret should contain environment variables that influence pgBackRest.
  pgbackrest: {}
    # Example S3 configuration
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_REGION: ""
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_KEY: ""
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_KEY_SECRET: ""
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_BUCKET: ""
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_ENDPOINT: "s3.amazonaws.com"

    # Example Azure configuration
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_AZURE_ACCOUNT: ""
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_AZURE_CONTAINER: ""
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_AZURE_KEY: ""
    # PGBACKREST_REPO1_AZURE_KEY_TYPE: ""

  # Selector used to provision your own Secret containing pgbackrest configuration details
  # This is mutually exclusive with `pgbackrest` option and takes precedence over it.
  # WARNING: Use this option with caution
  pgbackrestSecretName: ""

backup:
  enabled: false
  pgBackRest:
    # https://pgbackrest.org/configuration.html
    # Although not impossible, care should be taken not to include secrets
    # in these parameters. Use Kubernetes Secrets to specify S3 Keys, Secrets etc.
    compress-type: lz4
    process-max: 4
    start-fast: "y"
    repo1-retention-diff: 2
    repo1-retention-full: 2
    repo1-cipher-type: "none"

    # Example S3 configuration
    # repo1-type: s3
    # repo1-s3-region: us-east-2
    # repo1-s3-endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com

    # Example GCS configuration
    # repo1-type: gcs
    # repo1-path: /repo
    # repo1-gcs-bucket: your-bucket
    # repo1-gcs-key: /etc/pgbackrest_secrets/your-service-key.json

    # Example Azure configuration
    # repo1-type: azure
    # repo1-path: /repo

  # Overriding the archive-push/archive-get sections is most useful in
  # very high througput situations. Look at values/high_throuhgput_example.yaml for more details
  pgBackRest:archive-push: {}
  pgBackRest:archive-get: {}
  jobs:
      # name: needs to adhere to the kubernetes restrictions
      # type: can be full, incr or diff, see https://pgbackrest.org/user-guide.html
      # schedule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression
    - name: full-weekly
      type: full
      schedule: "12 02 * * 0"
    - name: incremental-daily
      type: incr
      schedule: "12 02 * * 1-6"
  # Extra custom environment variables for the backup container.
  envFrom:
  # - secretRef:
  #     name: extra-pgbackrest-secrets

  # Alternatively, you can expose individual environment variables:
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#envvar-v1-core
  # Although not impossible, care should be taken not to include secrets
  # in these parameters. Use Kubernetes Secrets to specify S3 Keys, Secrets etc.
  env:
  # - name: PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_BUCKET
  #   value: my_example_s3_bucket_for_backups
  # - name: PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_KEY_SECRET
  #   valueFrom:
  #     secretKeyRef:
  #       name: pgbackrest-dev-secrets
  #       key: repo1-s3-key-secret
  resources: {}
  # If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi

# When creating a *new* deployment, the default is to initialize (using initdb) the database.
# If however, you want to initialize the database using an existing backup, you can do so by
# configuring this section.
#
# WARNING: You *should not* run 2 identically named deployments in separate Kubernetes
#          clusters using the same S3 bucket for backups.
bootstrapFromBackup:
  enabled: false
  # Setting the s3 path is mandatory to avoid overwriting an already existing backup,
  # and to be sure the restore is explicitly the one requested.
  repo1-path:
  # Here you can (optionally) provide a Secret to configure the restore process further.
  # For example, if you need to specify a different restore bucket, you should set
  # PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_BUCKET: <base64 encoded value of the bucket> in these secrets
  secretName: pgbackrest-bootstrap


# Extra custom environment variables.
# These should be an EnvVar, as this allows you to inject secrets into the environment
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#envvar-v1-core
env:
#  - name: NOT_A_SECRET
#    value: "test"
#  - name: MYAPPLICATION_STANDBY_PASSWORDS
#    valueFrom:
#      secretKeyRef:
#        name: myapplication-passwords
#        key: standby

# Externally created Kubernetes secrets will be injected into the pods by referencing them here. You
# can also add more configuration options and secrets this way (see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables)
envFrom:
#  - configMapRef:
#      name: my-deployment-settings
#      optional: true


# This configuration will be passed on to Patroni directly, there are a few things that are
# injected/changed, these are:
#   - archive_command will be set to /bin/true if backup is disabled
#   - any context sensitive parameter (scope, namespace, name) will be overridden by the Kubernetes context
# https://patroni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SETTINGS.html#settings
patroni:
  log:
    level: WARNING
  # https://patroni.readthedocs.io/en/latest/replica_bootstrap.html#bootstrap
  bootstrap:
    method: restore_or_initdb
    restore_or_initdb:
      command: >
        /etc/timescaledb/scripts/restore_or_initdb.sh
        --encoding=UTF8
        --locale=C.UTF-8
      keep_existing_recovery_conf: true
    post_init: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/post_init.sh
    dcs:
      loop_wait: 10
      maximum_lag_on_failover: 33554432
      postgresql:
        parameters:
          archive_command: "/etc/timescaledb/scripts/pgbackrest_archive.sh %p"
          archive_mode: 'on'
          archive_timeout: 1800s
          #
          # Autovacuuming is very important to PostgreSQL. For TimescaleDB, in
          # most usecases the vacuuming part is of less importance (there are no deleted tuples to prune)
          # however, the autoanalyze bit (updating the statistics of the chunks) is important to help
          # in planning queries. Therefore we do some tuning of autovacuum to address these
          # TimescaleDB specific concerns.
          # We'd rather have autovacuum do things early, as this increases the changes that autovacuum
          # will find the buffers it needs in shared_buffers, instead of having to fetch them from disk.
          #
          autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor: 0.02
          # This allows us to auto-analyze at most 120 (pretty much empty) chunks every 5 seconds
          # This will ensure that we can have up-to-date statistics on inserts very, very quickly
          autovacuum_naptime: 5s
          autovacuum_max_workers: 10
          # We don't want vacuum work to be building up, therefore we increase
          # the cost limit so that the work to be done for vacuum will be done quickly.
          autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit: 500
          autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor: 0.05
          log_autovacuum_min_duration: 1min
          hot_standby: 'on'
          log_checkpoints: 'on'
          log_connections: 'on'
          log_disconnections: 'on'
          log_line_prefix: "%t [%p]: [%c-%l] %u@%d,app=%a [%e] "
          log_lock_waits: 'on'
          log_min_duration_statement: '1s'
          log_statement: ddl
          max_connections: 100
          max_prepared_transactions: 150
          shared_preload_libraries: timescaledb,pg_stat_statements
          ssl: 'on'
          ssl_cert_file: '/etc/certificate/tls.crt'
          ssl_key_file: '/etc/certificate/tls.key'
          tcp_keepalives_idle: 900
          tcp_keepalives_interval: 100
          temp_file_limit: 1GB
          timescaledb.passfile: '../.pgpass'
          unix_socket_directories: "/var/run/postgresql"
          unix_socket_permissions: '0750'
          wal_level: hot_standby
          wal_log_hints: 'on'
        use_pg_rewind: true
        use_slots: true
      retry_timeout: 10
      ttl: 30
  kubernetes:
    role_label: role
    scope_label: cluster-name
    use_endpoints: true
  postgresql:
    create_replica_methods:
    - pgbackrest
    - basebackup
    pgbackrest:
      command: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/pgbackrest_restore.sh
      keep_data: true
      no_params: true
      no_master: true
    basebackup:
    - waldir: "/var/lib/postgresql/wal/pg_wal"
    recovery_conf:
      restore_command: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/pgbackrest_archive_get.sh %f "%p"
    callbacks:
      on_role_change: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/patroni_callback.sh
      on_start: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/patroni_callback.sh
      on_reload: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/patroni_callback.sh
      on_restart: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/patroni_callback.sh
      on_stop: /etc/timescaledb/scripts/patroni_callback.sh
    authentication:
      replication:
        username: standby
      superuser:
        username: postgres
    listen: 0.0.0.0:5432
    pg_hba:
    - local     all             postgres                              peer
    - local     all             all                                   md5
    - hostnossl all,replication all                all                reject
    - hostssl   all             all                127.0.0.1/32       md5
    - hostssl   all             all                ::1/128            md5
    - hostssl   replication     standby            all                md5
    - hostssl   all             all                all                md5
    use_unix_socket: true
  restapi:
    listen: 0.0.0.0:8008

callbacks:
  # If set, this configMap will be used for the Patroni callbacks.
  configMap:  # example-patroni-callbacks

postInit:
  # A list of sources, that contain post init scripts.
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#projectedvolumesource-v1-core
  # These scripts are all projected to the same directory and will be executed
  # in sorted order only once: After a cluster initialization
  # Some examples:
  - configMap:
      name: custom-init-scripts
      optional: true
  - secret:
      name: custom-secret-scripts
      optional: true

# Values for defining the primary & replica Kubernetes Services.
service:
  primary:
    # One of (ClusterIP | LoadBalancer | NodePort). Headless services are not supported.
    type: ClusterIP
    # The port used by the service.
    port: 5432
    # Optional NodePort, only used for type `NodePort`.
    nodePort: null
    # Additional labels to be added to the Service.
    labels: {}
    # Additional annotations to be added to the Service.
    annotations: {}
    # Define extra fields to be interpolated into the Service spec.
    #
    # This allows for adding support for new features and functionality which may not yet
    # be directly supported in this chart.
    spec: {}
    # loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    # - "0.0.0.0/0"

  replica:
    # One of (ClusterIP | LoadBalancer | NodePort). Headless services are not supported.
    type: ClusterIP
    # The port used by the service.
    port: 5432
    # Optional NodePort, only used for type `NodePort`.
    nodePort: null
    # Additional labels to be added to the Service.
    labels: {}
    # Additional annotations to be added to the Service.
    annotations: {}
    # Define extra fields to be interpolated into the Service spec.
    #
    # This allows for adding support for new features and functionality which may not yet
    # be directly supported in this chart.
    spec: {}
    # loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    # - "0.0.0.0/0"

readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 30
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 6
  successThreshold: 1

persistentVolumes:
  # For sanity reasons, the actual PGDATA and wal directory will be subdirectories of the Volume mounts,
  # this allows Patroni/a human/an automated operator to move directories during bootstrap, which cannot
  # be done if we did not use subdirectories
  # https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html#CREATING-CLUSTER-MOUNT-POINTS
  data:
    enabled: true
    size: 2Gi
    ## database data Persistent Volume Storage Class
    ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
    ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
    ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
    ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
    ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
    ##
    storageClass: gp2
    # storageClassName: gp2
    # subPath: ""
    mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql"
    annotations: {}
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
  # WAL will be a subdirectory of the data volume, which means enabling a separate
  # volume for the WAL files should just work for new pods.
  wal:
    enabled: true
    size: 1Gi
    # subPath: ""
    storageClass: gp2
    # storageClassName: gp2
    # When changing this mountPath ensure you also change the following key to reflect this:
    # patroni.postgresql.basebackup.[].waldir
    mountPath: "/var/lib/postgresql/wal"
    annotations: {}
    accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
  # Any tablespace mentioned here requires a volume that will be associated with it.
  # tablespaces:
    # example1:
    #   size: 5Gi
    #   storageClass: gp2
    # example2:
    #   size: 5Gi
    #   storageClass: gp2

resources: {}
  # If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi

sharedMemory:
  # By default Kubernetes only provides 64MB to /dev/shm
  # /dev/shm is only used by PostgreSQL for work_mem for parallel workers,
  # so most will not run into this issue.
  # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28272
  #
  # If you do however run into:
  #
  #   SQLSTATE 53100
  #   ERROR:  could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.12345" to 4194304 bytes:
  #   No space left on device
  #
  # you may wish to use a mount to Memory, by setting useMount to true
  useMount: false

# timescaledb-tune will be run with the Pod resources requests or - if not set - its limits.
# This should give a reasonably tuned PostgreSQL instance.
# Any PostgreSQL parameter that is explicitly set in the Patroni configuration will override
# the auto-tuned variables.
timescaledbTune:
  enabled: true
  # For full flexibility, we allow you to override any timescaledb-tune parameter below.
  # However, these parameters only take effect on newly scheduled pods and their settings are
  # only visibible inside those new pods.
  # Therefore you probably want to set explicit overrides in patroni.bootstrap.dcs.postgresql.parameters,
  # as those will take effect as soon as possible.
  # https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-tune
  args: {}
    # max-conns: 120
    # cpus: 5
    # memory: 4GB

# pgBouncer does connection pooling for PostgreSQL
# https://www.pgbouncer.org/
# enabling pgBouncer will run an extra container in every Pod, serving a pgBouncer
# pass-through instance
pgBouncer:
  enabled: false
  port: 6432
  config:
  # DANGER: The below settings are considered to be safe to set, and we recommend
  # you do set these to appropriate values for you.
  # However, for flexibility, we do allow the override of any pg_bouncer setting
  # many of which are vital to the operation of this helm chart.
  # The values we do not suggest altering are set in the template
  # https://github.com/timescale/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/timescaledb-single/templates/configmap-pgbouncer.yaml#L35-L50
  # Only override these settings if you are confident of  what you are doing.
    server_reset_query: DISCARD ALL
    max_client_conn: 500
    default_pool_size: 12
    pool_mode: transaction
  pg_hba:
  - local     all postgres                   peer
  - host      all postgres,standby 0.0.0.0/0 reject
  - host      all postgres,standby ::0/0     reject
  - hostssl   all all              0.0.0.0/0 md5
  - hostssl   all all              ::0/0     md5
  - hostnossl all all              0.0.0.0/0 reject
  - hostnossl all all              ::0/0     reject
  # Secret should contain user/password pairs in the format expected by pgbouncer
  # https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#authentication-file-format
  # example:
  # userlist.txt: |
  #   "username" "hashedpassword"
  #   "username2" "hashedpassword2"
  userListSecretName:

networkPolicy:
  enabled: false
  prometheusApp: prometheus
  # Below you can specify a whitelist of Ingress rules, for more information:
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#the-networkpolicy-resource
  ingress:
  # - from:
  #   - podSelector:
  #       matchLabels:
  #         app: foo
  #   ports:
  #   - protocol: TCP
  #       port: 11111

# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector
nodeSelector: {}

# Prometheus exporter for PostgreSQL server metrics.
# https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter
prometheus:
  enabled: false
  image:
    repository: quay.io/prometheuscommunity/postgres-exporter
    tag: v0.11.1
    pullPolicy: Always
  # Extra custom environment variables for prometheus.
  # These should be an EnvVar, as this allows you to inject secrets into the environment
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#envvar-v1-core
  env:
  # - name: NOT_A_SECRET
  #   value: "test"
  # - name: MYAPPLICATION_STANDBY_PASSWORDS
  #   valueFrom:
  #     secretKeyRef:
  #       name: myapplication-passwords
  #       key: standby
  # Additional volumes for prometheus, e.g., to support additional queries.
  # These should be a Volume, as this allows you to inject any kind of Volume
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#volume-v1-core

  # Extra custom CLI arguments for postgres_exporter.
  args: []
  # - --collector.database=disabled
  volumes:
  # - name: exporter-config
  #   configMap:
  #     name: exporter-prometheus
  #     items:
  #       - key: metrics_queries
  #         path: queries.yaml
  # Additional volume mounts, to be used in conjunction with the above variable.
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#volumemount-v1-core
  volumeMounts:
  # - name: exporter-config
  #   mountPath: /var/exporter

podMonitor:
  # Specifies whether PodMonitor for Prometheus operator should be created
  enabled: false
  path: /metrics
  interval: 10s
  # scrapeTimeout: 30s
  # Specifies namespace, where PodMonitor should be installed
  # namespace: monitoring
  # labels:
  #   release: prometheus
  # honorLabels: true
  # metricRelabelings: []
  # podTargetLabels:
  #   - foo

# For new deployments, we would advise Parallel here, however as that change breaks previous
# deployments, it is set to OrderedReady here
podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady

# Annotations that are applied to each pod in the stateful set
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/
podAnnotations: {}

# Labels that are applied to each pod in the stateful set
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/
podLabels: {}

# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/
tolerations: []

# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity
affinity: {}

# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#topologyspreadconstraints
topologySpreadConstraints: []

## Use an alternate scheduler, e.g. "stork".
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
##
# schedulerName:

rbac:
  # Specifies whether RBAC resources should be created
  create: true

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  create: true
  # The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name:
  # A map of annotations to be set on the ServiceAccount
  annotations: {}

debug:
  # This setting is mainly for during development, debugging or troubleshooting.
  # This command will be executed *before* the main container starts. In the
  # example below, we can mimick a slow restore by sleeping for 5 minutes before starting
  execStartPre:  # sleep 300
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `kubectl get pv` and `kubectl get pvc` commands after you deploy the helm release?

Comment: @MuravyevMaxim please use below URL to access snippets

https://picallow.com/timescaledbk8stest/

Comment: Your pv is in pending status for some reason. You have to check the logs of aws-csi-ebs provisioner. Normally it's in kube-system namespace.

Comment: Thanks for "provisioner" hint, I noticed in my AWS EKS cluster "Amazon EBS CSI Driver" add-on was missing, after adding this I am able to get the PV and PVC's are getting success.

after this now I am stuck on another issue where my "Stateful Sets" are going into failure mode. please use this link to see the snippets (not able to post complete log file here)

https://picallow.com/stateful_set_error/

Comment: Just show output of kubectl describe statefulset/object

Comment: this is so much inconsistent, after deleting all the PV,PVC,Secrets. statefulset is working fine now!!! but for some reason below error is still coming into the log file. 

link
https://picallow.com/statefulseterror2/

Comment: @NamanJoshi, please try to avoid using picallow.com for snippets, as it seems they expire, and anyone who wants to contribute to your question can no longer follow the thread of what was happening